# how to specify options when using JavaCompiler interface

Tags: java

```
 JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, "cp", System.getProperties().getProperty("java.class.path"), sourceFile.getPath());
```

this not work, how  to pass classpath option to JavaCompiler instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to precede the argument with '-' i.e. `-cp` or `-classpath` as if you would use the command line javac. See also [javac](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)